# memory map for a file exists or not

Tags: c

I have to memory map a file if there is not already one for that file. The code I provided is not working. I am calling this function twice from another file and each time it is creating different mmapPtr.

```
char *mmapPtr;

void MemoryMapFile()
{

    int fd;
    struct stat sbuf;
    if(mmapPtr==NULL) <--- why is this executed when I called MemoryMapFile() second time
    {
        // get file descriptor of file
        if ((fd = open("example.c", O_RDONLY)) == -1) 
        {
            perror("open");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (stat("example.c", &sbuf) == -1) 
        {
            perror("stat");
            exit(1);
    }
        if ((data = mmap((caddr_t)0, sbuf.st_size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0)) ==  (caddr_t)(-1)) 
        {
            perror("mmap");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("mmap pointer %p \n",mmapPtr);
    }
```

Comment: What is the specific problem with the code,what line, show the struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If char* mmapPtr is not a global or static pointer the line

```
if(mmapPtr==NULL)
```

never returns true as an uninitialized pointer has a random value, not a NULL value.

If you declare

```
char *mmapPtr = NULL;
```

it should work,( ignoring possible other errors)

Comment: -1. Global variables and static variables are initialized by default. You don't need to specify 0, NULL or 0.0 to initialise them. Only if you want to have them a different value than 0 would you have to initialize them. Only `auto` variables have random values upon declaration.

Comment: @tristopia You are absolutely correct, but how do you know his pointer is global? Judging from the approval from OP, >>char *mmapPtr = NULL;<< was his problem and his pointer was not global nor static. I have fixed the answer and it should be correct now.

Answer (score 2):

1) mmapPtr needs an initial value for you to be able to compare it against NULL or whatever

```
char *mmapPtr = NULL;
```

2) Once this works and you entered the if block, you never assign mmapPtr any other value

```
mmapPtr = data; // I guess, as data is not defined in this snippet
```